# 403 Forbidden On Images

Tags: permissions, filesystems, http-status-code-403

I've setup a trio of subdomains on 1and1's web hosting, and quite frankly, their support has left much to be desired.
On all three, I cannot get images to show up. It looks like they're all "403 - Forbidden," but I am not sure why, nor why it's only the images directory.

Subdomains are these:

```
http://x1.keefermadness.com/
http://x2.keefermadness.com/ 
http://x3.keefermadness.com/
```

I've gone as far as setting the permissions to 777 on the dir and subdirs where images live.
Other externals on the site (like the .js file) all show up fine.
Images on the main domain are fine as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm interesting as they do appear if you open the images on their own http://x1.keefermadness.com/lib/img/home/home-featured01.jpg

Comment: It seems intermittent. Every once in a while, I get that `403 Forbidden` message. Something is up with your webhost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually was an issue with the .htaccess file.

I had long ago set it up to disallow hotlinking, but it was specific to the domain, and didn't take into account subdomains.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an issue with your WebHost as the problem occurs intermittently.

This seems to solve the problem for some people. When you request an image, add a random string as a query parameter.

when requesting the image, use

```
home-featured01.jpg?(randomly generated string)
```

Comment: A lot of the images are background images, do I do a string on the css inclusion as well?

Comment: Do check if the approach works with images, as it is not a sure-shot solution. CSS background images, might need to be dealt with separately.

Answer (score 0):

we removed the last line on the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?zzz\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?zzz\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|js|css|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

which was returning the forbidden action for images and css

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?zzz\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?zzz\.co.uk [NC]
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Old question but 403 problem on images can be a little trickier. Check permission of all the folders and the file itself in which the image is contained. Example

> /images/theme1/bg.jpg

check properties of /images folder, then theme1 folder and the file bg.jpg itself. **In my case everything was fine but the middle folder had 'no access' on `everyone` hence 403 forbidden error.**

[image]